# Não consigo usar o campo tipo Date. Estou usando Asp.Net C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```js
function set_dados_form(dados) {
  $('#id_cadastro').val(dados.Id);
  $('#txt_Nome').val(dados.Nome),
    $('#txt_Telefone').val(dados.Telefone),
    $('#txt_Endereco').val(dados.Endereco),
    $('#txt_Data').val(dados.DataNascimento),
    $('#cbx_Ativo').prop('checked', dados.Ativo);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">

  @Html.Label("txt_Data", "Data", new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="date" name="txt_Data" id="txt_Data" class="col-md-4 control-label" />

  </div>
</div>
```

---

Não consigo alimentar o campo Date. Com a Data que vem de uma consulta, está vindo um valor ex:"01/01/2017"(tipo uma string), mas ao colocar na propriedade val (referente ao jquery) não aparece coisa alguma. Alguém me ajuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando o valor em qual formato?

Se for nesse formato => "01/01/2017" está incorreto.
Primeiro você precisará formatar para esse = "2017-01-01" e então conseguirá atribuir.

Aqui vai um exemplo de como utilizar.

Explicação, coloquei o dbclick apenas para testar rapidamente se funcionária.
O que importa mesmo aqui é função **formataData**.
Ela deverá receber uma data no seguinte formato **'AAAA/MM/DD'**

então ela retornará uma data no formato aceito pelo seu campo data, que é **'AAAA-MM-DD'**

Lembrando que onde eu coloquei a data fixa, você deverá passar sua variável.

```
 $('#txt_Data').dblclick(function () {     


   $('#txt_Data').val(formataData('2017/04/01'));
})
function formataData(data) {
    var array = data.split('/');
    var data = array[0] + '-' + array[1] + '-' + array[2];

    return data;

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar aqui pra ver se dar certo.

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo, olha só o que me retornou -Date(765514800000)-

Comment: Você tem certeza que  dados.DataNascimento, está no formato citado? Porque o código que eu passei  foi testado.